# Модальное окно во врямя просмотра видео

Tags: всплывающее-окно

Может, кто сталкивался с решением задачи.

Есть iframe youtube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

и скрипт, который должен показывать алерт при достижении определенной секунды видео:

```
   <script>
var video = document.getElementsByID("video")[0];
var checkPoint = 3 // измерения в секундах
video.ontimeupdate = function () {
    if(video.currentTime != checkPoint) return;

    alert('hello')
}
   </script>
```

Как заставить его показывать алерт?

Comment: Для этого нужно обратиться непосредственно к элементу "video", в котором есть соотвествующие методы, включая "currentTime". А у iframe такого нет.

Comment: пожалуйста, если не сложно, пример напишите )

Comment: [Масса примеров][1]
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: я понял, про что вы, меня именно интересует с youtube iframe, пример marketium.ru/hollie-steel/ 1.38 мин

Comment: На этом сайте разработчики тоже ничего не имеют с тэгом "video". Я не вдавался в подробности, но они играются с куками, и сами хитро подсчитывают время просмотра видео. При желании можно провести reverse engineering.